# Show the firebase event_params key-value data into the single row using Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to perform a Google BigQuery on the Firebase stored events. I have executed the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` LIMIT 6
```

which has the following result:

```
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Row |   date   |  name  | event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value |
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|   1 | 20200922 | Event1 | errorName        | BLE_Not_connected               |
|     |          |        | appDetails       | 2.2.2                           |
|     |          |        | errorDetails     | iOS-Error                       |
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

So, here row-1 has multiple entries of `event_params.key` and their value shows on `event_params.value.string_value` column. Now, I want to perform a Google Big-Query which flattens the `event_params.key` column value and show a result below

```
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Row |   date   |  name  | errorName        | appDetails  | errorDetails      |
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
|   1 | 20200922 | Event1 | BLE_Not_connected| 2.2.2       | iOS-Error         |
+-----+----------+--------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
  SELECT date, name, """ || 
    STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(key = '""" || key || """', value.string_value, NULL)) AS """ || key, ', ') 
  || """
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t, t.event_params
  GROUP BY date, name
  """
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT key
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t, t.event_params
  )
);
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row date        name    errorName           appDetails  errorDetails     
1   20200922    Event1  BLE_Not_connected   2.2.2       iOS-Error
```